# How could Firefox 81.0 support SystemMediaTransportControls in Windows?

Tags: firefox, uwp

I did some search first and found that the SystemMediaTransportControls doesn't have property DualApiPartition. and the Firefox is not a UWP Application. How does Firefox support SystemMediaTransportControls in its 81.0 release?
More generally, how can I use UWP APIs which doesn't have DualApiPartion in a normal win32 application?
Thanks for any help.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-audio-or-video-playback-your-keyboard?redirectslug=control-audio-or-video-playback-your-headset-or-keyboard&redirectlocale=en-US

Comment: Seems like black magic. I came here with the same question. Also through [Firefox' code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/windows/WindowsSMTCProvider.cpp#102). Maybe it's best to ask Mozilla for help as they are the only ones who found out how to use that Windows API.